# Add specific string to core dump to the beginning of it

Tags: c++, linux, coredump

I have a large coredumps, say, 120+ Gigabytes.

I need to get program version from it, so I add global constant (pseudo code):

```
static const char* const = "MAGIC_KEYWORD_FOR_GREPPING_" + MY_PROGRAM_VERSION;
```

Is it possible to place it to beginning of coredump, so grepping will be faster?

Comment: `"MAGIC_KEYWORD_FOR_GREPPING_" + MY_PROGRAM_VERSION`. That's not going to do what you think it does. Try `std::cout << "Hello"+1;`.

Comment: @MSalters Look at "pseudo code" words in question.

Answer (score 1):

Coredumps are created by the operating system, not by applications that cause them. There is no way for the OS to know the value of some variable in your program. You can adjust the names of your coredumps by setting `core_pattern` to have the executable name in the coredump's filename included. This [man page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/core.5.html) has the specifiers' description.

It might be that your OS generates coredumps by piping through some application - if `cat /proc/sys/kernel/core_pattern` returns a string starting with `|` (for example mine is `|/usr/share/apport/apport %p %s %c %P`) then you have to adjust the parameters accordingly. See [this link](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/192716/how-to-set-the-core-dump-file-location-and-name) for more details

Comment: Great advice! Thank you!

Comment: But can I change core_pattern just for my process?

Comment: @vladon if you change the name of coredumps it will be for all coredumps. If different programs generate coredumps then just add `%e` to the coredump name which will add the executable's name to the coredump name. If you have the same program (same binary filename) at different locations then use `%E` so that you have a full path you can `grep` for in coredumps. If you set coredump pattern to `core_%e` and `prog1` and `prog2` fail and coredumps are generated then you have two coredumps: `core_prog1` and `core_prog2`. Adding timestamp is also a good idea. Just check all available specifiers :)